# Finding a basis in Rn for an arbitrary non-standard vector

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find a basis for R<sup>n</sup> that includes a nonstandard basis vector (x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ...x<sub>n</sub>)

I would like to know if my reasoning is 'proofy' enough to answer the above question sufficiently. Would I lose any points because I did not provide enough information or examples?

The nonstandard basis vector (x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ...x<sub>n</sub>) must be a linear combination of the standard basis vectors.

The basis of R<sup>n</sup> must have n number of vectors to be a basis of R<sup>n</sup>. All basis that includes a nonstandard basis vector (x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ...x<sub>n</sub>) will form a basis with any combination of n-1 standard basis vectors.

Comment: To be concrete, let $n = 3$ and $x = (1,1,0)$, and let $e_1, e_2$, and $e_3$ be the standard basis vectors for $\mathbb R^3$. Are you saying that $\{ x, e_1, e_2\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: Evan what you claimed is not true always.The nonstandard basis vector should not be spanned by the other (n-1) standard basis vectors if your claim has to be correct

Comment: I was trying to claim that the combination of a nonstandard basis vector + standard basis vectors (but not all of them so that there are n vectors in R<sup>n</sup> will create a basis for R<sup>n</sup>. This idea came from when I tried to find a basis for R<sup>2</sup> that included the vector (2,2). I found that the S<sub>1</sub> = {(2,2), (0,1)} and S<sub>2</sub> = {(2,2), (1,0) were both were both sets that spanned R<sup>2</sup> that contained the vector (2,2). I was trying to generalize this insight by finding a way to abstractly express this for R<sup>n</sup>

Comment: @littleO yes that any combination between x and c1, c2, and c3 can become a basis. so {x, c1, c2}, {x, c2, c3}, {x, c1, c3} are all basis vectors of R<sup>3</sup> ...why are none of my notations working? :(

Comment: @EvanKim But, $\{ x, e_1, e_2 \}$ is not a basis for $\mathbb R^3$. Even though this set contains three vectors, it is not a *linearly independent* set of vectors.

Comment: hmm. The textbook asked to find a basis that includes the vector (2,2) in R^2. They gave the answer as S = {(2,2), (1,0)}. I setup a system of equations, set the vectors = to 0 and got the R^2 identity matrix. Therefore I concluded the system was linearly independent. 

If x = (3,3,3), I set up the linear system as  
3 + 3 + 3 = 0  

1 + 0 + 0 = 0  

0 + 1 + 0 = 0

There is a unique solution because the determinant is not 0 for matrix A and augmenting the matrix & reducing to RREF shows that the solution is (0,0,0) which means its linearly independent, no?